# Как вместо одного блока поставить другой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как вместо блока с id=”tr” поставить блок с id=”fa” ?

Comment: Нет, не нужно.

Comment: Стили должны сохраняться?

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает ответ @0xFFh ? Телепатией, к сожалению, не обучали.

Answer (score 2):

Удобнее иметь один блок и по мере необходимости изменять его контент. Например, даже так:

```
$("#tr").html($("#fa").html());
```